# send an email from office 365 as from address not same as Credential Address

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

I want to send an email in ASP.net where I want to hide the email address that I send to the customers. I want to show them a different email address in the From box so for e.g. I want to send an email from abc@abc.com, this email is authenticated. When the end user receives the email in their inbox, they will see a different address called test@test.com. They can reply to this email. I have this code so far:

```
testMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(txtemail.Text.Tostring(), "To Name"));
msg.From = new MailAddress("abc@abc.com", "From Name");
msg.Subject = "This is a test";
msg.Body = "Hello, this is a test email";
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("userName", "PASS");
client.Port = 121;
client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.EnableSsl = true;
```

I don't want the customers to see my abc@abc.com email address. Instead of that, I want them to see Test@test.com. How can I achieve this? They can reply to test@test.com. I don't want them to reply to abc@abc.com. I am not sure which settings should I change to do this?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try setting from address to test@test.com in the code? What happened? `msg.From = new MailAddress("test@test.com", "From Name");`

Comment: yes, it works. Only issues is it send the emails from test@test.com too. My company wants me to send an email from abc@abc.com because this is an authenticated email and test@test.com is not authenticated. Its antonymous email.

Comment: `Only issues is it send the emails from test@test.com too` what does this mean? Are there two emails begin sent? `I want them to see Test@test.com.` is this not happening with the code change I suggested?

Comment: My company wants me to send the email that is secured, but they dont want the customer to reply to that email. They want another email adress to display in the customers from email box so that they can reply to that email

Comment: You can achieve that with the code I suggested. What the issue you see facing in using that approach?

Comment: Yes, its working that way